# Is there bootable software to extract drivers in Windows?

Tags: windows, drivers

I have seen many software like DriverGenius which makes the backup of all drivers.

But suppose if my Windows become un-bootable then is there any software which extract drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This portable backup software](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drvback/) can be integrated into a Bart PE or UBCD boot cd

[UBCD for Windows](http://www.ubcd4win.com) is reported to have a driver backup software